# How do I prevent <div> from overlapping on zoom?

Tags: html, css

I am displaying three `div`'s side by side, they look well at normal screen size but on zooming screen as the `div` shrinks text inside it also shrinks and images seem to be cut (size of image is being cut on further zoom). Bottom line I don't want content inside `div`s messed up on zooming, tried `overflow: scroll` for `body` but on zooming no scroll bar appears. I think scroll bar would help in keeping the content inside `div` safe.

[jsfiddle this will help you understand](http://jsfiddle.net/begginer/s2c1bneu/)

```
<div id='container' style='width:100%;'>
<div class='left' style='height:20px;width:21%;float:left;border:1px solid black;box-sizing: border-box;height:200px;'>
</div>
<div class='center' style='height:20px;width:56%;float:left;border:1px solid blue;box-sizing: border-box;height:200px;'>
</div>
<div class='right' style='height:20px;width:23%;float:right;border:1px solid red;box-sizing: border-box;height:200px;'>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using % in width be carefull because the border, margin, padding all counts to the width calculation, thats probably why your code fails.

To make it work you can use box-sizing: border-box; in your divs take a look:

```
<div id='container' style='width:100%;'>
<div class='left' style='width:21%;float:left;box-sizing: border-box;'>
</div>
<div class='center' style='width:56%;display:inline-block;box-sizing: border-box;'>
</div>
<div class='right' style='width:23%;float:right;box-sizing: border-box;'>
</div>
</div>
```

Take a look at this fiddle fully working http://jsfiddle.net/0heq8dz3/

Comment: this didn't help ; I have updated my question with jsfiddle now you will understand what i mean

Comment: check this fiddle with overflow examples, the first two divs overflow: hidden the third div with overflow:scrool http://jsfiddle.net/0duczra5/